# Chromium browser headless for PDF production not working

Tags: google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to generate PDFs from HTML. I have this working on my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop.

A minimal example is;

```
chromium-browser --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf='/var/www/test/test.pdf' 'https://www.google.com'
```

When I try to execute this on an Ubuntu 20.04 server, I'm getting;

[1102/161822.295586:ERROR:headless_shell.cc(628)] Writing to file /var/www/test/test.pdf was unsuccessful, could not open file: FILE_ERROR_NOT_FOUND

If I change the --print-to-pdf path to the home directory of the user, it works. A directory outside of the users home even if owned by the user and with 777 permissions fails.

I'm at a loss as to how to troubleshoot this. I've tried adding the --enable-logging flag, but this doesn't seem to do anything. I've checked the logs; nothing.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue on Ubuntu 22.04. Worked fine on macOS Monterey. Any ideas how you got round this issue? I just worked around by making a `~/.tmp` folder and using that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using chromium-browser, directly call the chrome executable like this.

```
/snap/chromium/current/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf='/var/www/test/test.pdf' 'https://www.google.com'
```

OR

Remove or rename /usr/bin/chromium-browser and create symbolic link like this

```
ln -s /snap/chromium/current/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome /usr/bin/chromium-browser
```

Then you can run it as you did

```
chromium-browser --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf='/var/www/test/test.pdf' 'https://www.google.com'
```

I don't know what was the cause of the issue, for some reason it can't write inside /var, but this fixed it for me.